# Inheritance model for static variables and methods

Tags: design-patterns, inheritance, model, static, subclass

*I am doing this for Objective C but this is a common behavior among various common languages.*

I know that Static variables or methods are not inherited to subclasses, however i would want to know which is the best approach to do the following:

**I have several classes (say 10) with the following base model:**

```objc
static id A

@interface MyClass

 + (void) doSomethingWithA;

@end


@implementation MyClass
    + (void) doSomethingWithA {
        [A doSomething];
        [A doOtherThing];
        //do more things
    }

@end
```

**The code is exactly the same for all the classes, but as the methods are static (I only want to have one instance of A per class) then I can't use subclassing to avoid code repeating.**

**I would really want to avoid copying and pasting so much code.**

Which is the best practice in this case?

Comment: Is it convenient to you to use inheritance? Consider component approach over inheritance - move all logic working with static to separate component class and attach it to your classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you make it instance methods, with use of inheritance and everything you need, and create static instances (eg. singleton) to call them?

Comment: Because the singleton uses a Static instance as you said, which returns to the same problem.

Comment: When you can write 10 classes with 10 methods, then you can have 10 instances with a static accessor, but you don't have to write the code 10 times and you can make use of inheritance.

Comment: Ok I guess that was the cleanest solution I could achieve.